# ng-animate to created a slideIn / slideOut transition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angular-ui, ng-animate

I am struggle to execute a simple slide transition using angular, i know how to do this perfectly using jquery, however i am trying make use of angular and it's tools. This here provides an example of what have done thus far[Click Here for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OBFmDdzMnTJNxjsnPgib?p=preview) - click on the link shop..

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <header ng-app="menu" id="main-nav">
            <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
            <ul id="nav" ng-controller="subNavController">
                <li><a href="/">search</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="hiddenMenu" ng-click="navMenu = !navMenu">shop</a>
                    <div ng-show="navMenu" class="block"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/">Join LYB</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">LYB Mix Series</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">English</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
</div>
```

controller

```
var app = angular.module("menu", []);
app.controller("subNavController", function ($scope){
        $scope.menu = function (){
            $scope.navMenu = ! $scope.navMenu;
        };
        $scope.navMenu = false;
```

});

Does anyone know how to achieve a slide in effect using angular

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I achieved a similar effect, but in my case it was sliding the div in from the top. You should be able to switch the few references to `top` to suit your case. This requires [angular-animate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and the class specified as the name of the animation to be applied to the element (`.loading` in my example).

```
app.animation('.loading', function() {
    return {
      addClass : function(element, className, done) {
        if(className == 'ng-hide') {
          jQuery(element).animate({
            top: '-100px'
          }, 1000, done);
        }
        else {
          done();
        }
      },
      removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
        if(className == 'ng-hide') {
          element.css('top','-100px');

          /* remove it early so you can animate on it since
             it is not possible using element.css() to set
             a style using !important */
          element.removeClass('ng-hide'); 
          jQuery(element).animate({
            top:0
          }, 0, done);
        }
        else {
          done();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```